# Testing statistical significance of empirical distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that we have an empirical distribution $f_X(x)$ which says $$P(X>1000) = 0.05$$ in any given unit time period. I.e. the exceedance probability of 1000 is $0.05$, so we would expect the event $X>1000$ to occur every $\frac{1}{0.05} = 20$ time periods

Suppose that now we observe using historic data of $X$ that the event $X>1000$ occurs twice in the last ten time periods. I am trying to test if this is statistically significant to question the empirical distribution which assumed that we would observe the event $X>1000$ 1 in every 20 time periods.

To put it into context, I'm looking at historical data and the time period is the number of years. The emperical distribution is for a one year time period and has $P(X>1000) = 0.05$, so we expect the event $X>1000$ to be a one-in-twenty year event. Looking at the past ten years of data, I see the event has occurred twice already, and in fact we have also observed a few 1-in-50 year events from the last ten years. I feel as though it is enough to question the emperical model, but I want to be able to say we can reject it with say a $95%$  percent confidence interval.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit of a stretch given such limited data. The data over the last $10$ years is likely more accurate/reliable in determining the actual distribution. However, the probability of getting two extreme $(.05)$ events in $10$ years is:

$p = \binom{10}{2}\cdot .05^2\cdot .95^8 = .074$

As $.074 > .05$, we fail to reject the null hypothesis as the result is not statistically significantly different.

A far more reliable method, assuming the distribution is normal, would be one that takes into account the mean and standard deviation of $10$ years of data instead of just $2$ extreme events.

Comment: The problem is for the historical data, we only have one sample point on each year - giving us ten sample points all together making it very difficult to fit a distribution around. What I'm doing is looking at each historic year, and getting the implied probability from the distribution.So two of ten years I saw the event X > 1000, and according the this distribution that only has a 0.05 chance of happening in any one given year, let alone ten. So it "feels" like it should be a rejection. Perhaps some sort of binomial testing is required? Not sure.

Comment: @DH, this is what my calculation is, a binomial probability. How many sample points do you have for the 1 year empirical data and how does time affect the result?

Comment: 1000 sample points for the empirical data; just best assuming time does not affect the result.

Comment: 1000 points, in that case my result stands, tenuous as it is due to the limitations in the data, but you can't reject the probability of .05 in getting x>1000 for a population of 1000 based on a .074 probability of getting 2 out of 10, x>1000. You don't have the evidence to say it is any different. Finally, how critical is this result in a practical sense? What are the consequences of making an error in sticking with p = .05?